# Understanding junit.framework.AssertionFailedError in Java/Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ant

### Scenario:

I have a `ProductManager` interface:

```
public interface ProductManager extends Serializable{
    public void increasePrice(int percentage);
    public List<Product> getProducts();
}
```

And an implementing class `SimpleProductManager`

```
public class SimpleProductManager implements ProductManager {
    private List<Product> products;

    public void increasePrice(int percentage) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

I am using the [Spring official docs](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part3.html#step3.2) and trying to understand the
following 3 tests for the increasePrice() method:

```
public void testIncreasePriceWithNullListOfProducts() {
    try {
        productManager = new SimpleProductManager();
        productManager.increasePrice(POSITIVE_PRICE_INCREASE);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        fail("Products list is null.");
    }
}

public void testIncreasePriceWithEmptyListOfProducts() {
    try {
        productManager = new SimpleProductManager();
        productManager.setProducts(new ArrayList<Product>());
        productManager.increasePrice(POSITIVE_PRICE_INCREASE);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        fail("Products list is empty.");
    }
}

public void testIncreasePriceWithPositivePercentage() {
    productManager.increasePrice(POSITIVE_PRICE_INCREASE);
    double expectedChairPriceWithIncrease = 22.55;
    double expectedTablePriceWithIncrease = 165.11;

    List<Product> products = productManager.getProducts();
    Product product = products.get(0);
    assertEquals(expectedChairPriceWithIncrease, product.getPrice());

    product = products.get(1);
    assertEquals(expectedTablePriceWithIncrease, product.getPrice());
}
```

### Question:

Why is it that when I run the `ant tests` for these 3 methods, the testcase `testIncreasePriceWithEmptyListOfProducts` fails with a `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Products list is empty`.

```
[junit] Testcase: testIncreasePriceWithNullListOfProducts(springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests): Caused an ERROR
    [junit] null
    [junit] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    [junit]     at springapp.service.SimpleProductManager.increasePrice(SimpleProductManager.java:12)
    [junit]     at springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests.testIncreasePriceWithNullListOfProducts(SimpleProductManagerTests.java:67)
    [junit] 
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testIncreasePriceWithEmptyListOfProducts(springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests):    FAILED
    [junit] Products list is empty.
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Products list is empty.
    [junit]     at springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests.testIncreasePriceWithEmptyListOfProducts(SimpleProductManagerTests.java:81)
    [junit] 
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testIncreasePriceWithPositivePercentage(springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests): Caused an ERROR
    [junit] null
    [junit] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    [junit]     at springapp.service.SimpleProductManager.increasePrice(SimpleProductManager.java:12)
    [junit]     at springapp.service.SimpleProductManagerTests.testIncreasePriceWithPositivePercentage(SimpleProductManagerTests.java:86)
```

Shouldn't it throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`(like the other 2 test cases) since the method `increasePrice` has not yet been implemented?

Comment: I haven't looked at the details of your code, but just wanted to point out that the link you are reading is really old!!!

Comment: @geoand: Thanks for pointing out. I am new to Spring and TDD. Do you have any link to suggest which covers all these stuffs thoroughly?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the guides at https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***testIncreasePriceWithEmptyListOfProducts()*** you catch all Exceptions. So you also catch the UnsupportedOperationException.

While in ***testIncreasePriceWithNullListOfProducts()*** you only catch NullPointerExceptions and the UnsupportedOperationException is thrown.